# Is there a note taking app that can synchronise across computers?

Tags: software-recommendation, tomboy, notes

I use Tomboy notes and have been synching across computers using Ubuntu One. However, the 11.10 "upgrade" has broken Tomboy Notes and Ubuntu One synchronisation, numerous bugs are reported and it affects a large number of users. Since Tomboy Notes will not be default in future releases I have my doubts this will ever be fixed, since bug fixing has adopted low priority compared to desktop environments. Does anyone know of a good alternative that allows synchronisation in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Every software that allows to choose where to save its documents is elegible for synchronization.

An interesting note taking software I would suggest is zim, available in the repos.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into "Nevernote" (or "NixNote" as it has apparently been renamed):
    http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/

It is an opensource clone that is compatible with EverNote:
    http://www.evernote.com/

There's also an Ubuntu PPA for it:
    http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/nevernote-ubuntu-ppa.html

Once you install NeverNote, you can then synchronize it with your Evernote id and access and edit these files on a Windows, Apple iOS, or Android system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ThetaPad (http://thetapad.com). It is cross platfor, offers fast sync between devices.Easy to write notes from anywhere, even if you're offline

Comment: Note: this answer was written by the developer of ThetaPad

Answer (score 0):

- **Evernote** – Tusk is an unofficial, featureful, open source, community-driven, free Evernote app. Through the inclusion of optional themes, keyboard shortcuts, custom tweaks, a tray icon, and more, Tusk integrates the Evernote web app with the Linux desktop in ways a regular browser tab can't. To install it type:

  ```
  sudo snap install tusk
  ```

  Features

  • Black, Dark, Sepia & Vibrant themes
  • Focus, Compact & Auto-Night modes
  • Local & global keyboard shortcuts
  • Customizable keyboard shortcuts
  • Export notes as PDF & markdown files
  • Note printing
  • Scalable interface
  • Note navigation
  • Cross-platform
  • Automatic updates
  • Deep OS integration
  • Drag and drop files
- **Simplenote** – Simplenote is an easy way to keep notes, lists, ideas and more. Your notes stay in sync with all of your devices for free. Simplenote is now available for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS and the web. To install it type:

  ```
  sudo snap install simplenote
  ```
- **Google Keep** – Google Keep is a notetaking service developed by Google. Google Keep is available on the web, and has mobile apps for Android and iOS. Google Keep offers a variety of tools for taking notes, including text, lists, images and audio.
- **Carnet** – Carnet is a powerful notetaking app the purpose of which is not only to write your shopping list but can also be used to write longer texts, stories, etc. Carnet is available on Android and Linux, also on your web browser with full compatibility with Windows, Mac and Linux, with sync capabilities. To install it type:

  ```
  sudo snap install carnet
  ```

  Features

  • Complete editor: bold/italic/underline/color/highlight
  • Import from Google Keep (only on desktop, then sync on mobile)
  • Insert images / review
  • Open HTML format
  • Organize with folders and choose root storage folder depending on your needs
  • Keywords
  • Quickly see your recent notes
  • Search your notes
  • Protect the app with a pin code (won't encrypt notes) on Android
  • Statistics: words/sentences/characters
  • Sync with NextCloud
  • Record audio
  • Online editor as a NextCloud App